# C++: including header file results in "symbol(s) not found for architecture", while including .cpp file works

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, ld, clion

I'm compiling a project that has several header files, one of them is a general "utils" file with general-purpose functions.

When I include the header file for this utils file, compilation fails (see error below), but when I include the actual .cpp file, it works.

I am using a CMakeLists.txt file with CLion, on MacOS High Sierra.

A minimal equivalent project that fails in the same way:

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "util.h"

int main() {
    print("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

**util.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


template<typename T>
void print(T thing_to_print);
```

**util.cpp:**

```
#include "util.h"

template <typename T>
void print(T thing_to_print){
    std::cout << thing_to_print << std::endl;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(example)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

SET(UTILS_MINIMAL_LIB_FILES util.h util.cpp)
add_library(utils_lib_minimal ${UTILS_MINIMAL_LIB_FILES})

add_executable(main_test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main_test utils_lib_minimal)
```

**Build fails:**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "void print<char const*>(char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld:  symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

However, when I change the include statement to :

```
#include "util.cpp"
```

The compilation completes successfully.

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might move implementations of templates to header file. [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/3309790)

Comment: Thanks so much @songyuanyao, that is indeed the solution. Please feel free to post as an answer so I can mark it as such.

Comment: Well if that's the solution then the question should be marked as duplicated, as @molbdnilo did. :)